# why should we use inheritance between A (super) & B (sub) instead of creating them separately and instantiate A from B?

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

```
class A {
    public void get(int a) {
       System.out.println("a is"+a);
    }
}

class B extends A {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        get(5);
    }
}
```

EDIT by Peter Lawrey: Taking the liberty of asking a question based on the code provided.

Why is it that a static method cannot directly use an instance method, even if its defined in a parent class?

Comment: Your question doesn't currently make sense. What does "creating objects to super class from subclass" even mean? Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: @JonSkeet I think he meant, instead of doing this `public class Foo extends Bar`, we can create an instance of `Bar` and use it inside `Foo`.

Comment: Next time, please make sure not to change the content of your question so that people's answers look off topic. What do you want to know now? Why inheritance or why doesn't the code work?

Comment: @GEEK max, to answer my revised question, A `static` method has not instance and `get(5)` requires an instance.  Being called in a sub-class does not change this.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed the question doesn't make sense but I believe it's not too hard to guess
what the question is about.

My guess for a rephrasal: why should we use inheritance between A (super) & B (sub) instead of creating them separately and instantiate A from B.

The main reasons for inheritance I would say:

1. Code reusability
2. Polymorphism
3. Code extension made easier, very much related to 1)
4. ...
5. ...

Answer (score 1):

Because `get()` is **method** and must be invoked on instance.

```
new B().get(5);
new A().get(1);
```

You call it in `static main()`, which is class **function**.

```
B.exampleFunction();
```

Answer (score 0):

The method `main` is static (can be called without actually having an instance of `B`), while the `get` method is not. You can only access this "instance method" if you actually have an instance of `A` or `B`. The following should work.

```
class A
{
    int a; // <- What's this for?

    void get(int a)
    {
        system.out.println("a is"+a.toString());
    }
}

class B extends A
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        B b = new B();
        b.get(5);
    }
}
```

But actually, the following sample demonstrates even better what you're asking:

```
class A
{
    void get(int a)
    {
        system.out.println("a is "+a.toString()+" in instance of A");
    }
}

class B extends A
{
    void get(int a)
    {
        system.out.println("a is "+a.toString()+" in instance of B");
    }
}

class C
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        A a = new A();
        a.get(5);

        B b = new B();
        b.get(5);
    }
}
```

Comment: if i write static before get is it correct?

Comment: You could, but you shouldn't. In case of the class definition you provided for `A`, the method may be static, as it does not depend on any other instance specific data. Usually, it is really bad practice to make everything static, as you lose all the advantages of object orientated paradigms. Rather look at my sample code.

Comment: no i did not get the output doing that way

Comment: I suggest you google for when to make methods static in Java. There will be lots of discussions about the whens and whys and why nots.

Comment: Did you debug and make sure that the `main` method in `B` is actually called? The way you defined your classes, `B` is the "main class" of your application, as it contains the `main` method, so you must make sure to "run" `B`. In my second sample, it's the `C` class that must be run.

Comment: yea i have checked its not working

Comment: I'm modifying the code slightly to avoid errors appending `int`s to `String`s. I also forgot to derive `B` from `A`.

Comment: when i compiled ur first code block i got an error package system does not exist

Comment: Of course I assumed that overall your code compiles and that you posted only a snipped from your code. I suggest you google for Java beginner's tutorials and make them compile. When they do, insert the code I created.